# Munkre topology Section 25 question 1

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness, path-connected

$a)$What are the components and path components of $R_l$ ?

$b)$What are the continuous
maps$ f : R → R_l$?

my attempt: i know that $ R_l$is totally disconnected....

Comment: And what is $\mathbb{R}_l$?

Comment: lower limit topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that $\mathbb{R}_l$ is totally disconneted and since $\mathbb R$ is connected, then you now that the answer to (b) is: only the constant functions.

On the other hand, since $\mathbb{R}_l$ is totally disconnected, its only connected non-empty subsets are the singletons. And this implies that its only path-connected non-empty subsets are the singletons too.

Comment: @ jose caros  santos  sir...how  can i   claim  that   $f $  must  be constant.?

Comment: @lomber Because $f(\mathbb{R})$ is connected and therefore it cannot have more than one point.

Comment: thanks  a lots @Jose carlos sir